# How to prevent json4s from rendering null values?

Tags: json, scala, jackson, json4s

How do I prevent json4s rendering null values when converting an object/JObject into a json string?

In Jackson you can do this by doing this:

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
```

How can I do the same thing in json4s?

**Example**

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
import org.json4s.{Extraction, NoTypeHints}

case class Book(title: String, author: String)

implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

val bookJValue = Extraction.decompose(Book(null, "Arthur C. Clark"))
# JObject(List((title,JNull), (author,JString(Arthur C. Clark))))

val compacted = compact(render(bookJValue))
# {"title":null,"author":"Arthur C. Clark"}
```

**I'd like the compacted json be this:**

```
{"author":"Arthur C. Clark"}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
case class Book(title: Option[String], author: String)
val b = Book(None, "Arthur C. Clark")
println(write(b))
res1:> {"author":"Arthur C. Clark"}
```

You can use `Option` to define variable. if it is none, it will not serialize this variable.

There is another way to do this by using `removeField` after you `decompose` your `object`, like:

```
bookJValue.removeFile {
   case (_, JNull) => true
   case _ => false
}
```

Comment: In my case I don't control the code where the Book is defined. Sorry my question wasn't clear enough. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create your own custom serializer. Follow me.

First of all make small change in `formats`:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new BookSerializer
```

After that build your own serializer/deserializer:

```
class BookSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Book](format => (
  {
    case JObject(JField("title", JString(t)) :: JField("author", JString(a)) ::Nil) =>
      new Book(t, a)
  },
  {
    case x @ Book(t: String, a: String) =>
      JObject(JField("title", JString(t)) ::
        JField("author", JString(a)) :: Nil)
    case Book(null, a: String) =>
      JObject(JField("author", JString(a)) :: Nil) // `title` == null
  }
  ))
```

The first part is deserializer (convert data from json to case class) and the second is serializer (conversion from case class to json). I've added case of `title == null`. You can easily add cases as many as you need.

The whole listing:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Extraction}
import org.json4s._


case class Book(title: String, author: String)

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new BookSerializer
class BookSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Book](format => (
  {
    case JObject(JField("title", JString(t)) :: JField("author", JString(a)) ::Nil) =>
      new Book(t, a)
  },
  {
    case x @ Book(t: String, a: String) =>
      JObject(JField("title", JString(t)) ::
        JField("author",   JString(a)) :: Nil)
    case Book(null, a: String) =>
      JObject(JField("author",   JString(a)) :: Nil) // `title` == null
  }
  ))

val bookJValue = Extraction.decompose(Book(null, "Arthur C. Clark"))
val compacted = compact(render(bookJValue))
```

Output:

```
compacted: String = {"author":"Arthur C. Clark"}
```

You can find additional information on the page of [json4s project](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serializing-non-supported-types).